# Review's Track Changes has rendered my VBA Project Unviewable

Tags: excel, vba

I selected 'Track Changes' from the Review tab after writing a VBA script. However, now when I try to view my VBA code, I receive a pop up saying 'Project Is Unviewable'. Why is this? How can I reverse it? I am using Excel 2013 and the file is on a server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you choose [Track Changes](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Track-changes-in-a-shared-workbook-70CD72CF-44E9-488F-A29F-99DC3DE0DBB2) in an Excel workbook, the workbook is shared. If the workbook contains recorded macros or a VBA project, you will receive this notification/confirmation/warning.

[image: Track Changes disables viewing/editing VBA]

> This workbook contains macros recorded or written in Visual Basic. Macros cannot be viewed or edited in shared workbooks.

If you try to view/edit your VBA project through Developer ► Code ► Visual Basic or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>, you will receive the following.

[image: Project is unviewable.]

**Solution:**

To get back access to your VBA project, the minimum you need to do is remove shared access. Choose Review ► Changes ► Share Workbook.

[image: Turn Track Changes Off]

Uncheck *'Allow changes by more than one user at the same time. This also allows workbook merging.'* and click <kbd>OK</kbd> in the lower right. You will get a final confirmation.

[image: Confirm stop tracking]

Click <kbd>OK</kbd> and get back to writing code.

There are additional options for keeping/rejecting changes as well as recording or printing the changes. See [Track changes in a shared workbook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Track-changes-in-a-shared-workbook-70CD72CF-44E9-488F-A29F-99DC3DE0DBB2#bm8) for specifics on those topics.